# How to turn off AOS animation in mobile screens?

Tags: javascript, css

Can anyone please tell me how to turn of animations of my page when it’s being viewed by a mobile device?

I’m using aos library for css to add some animation to my page. But I want to turn that animation off on mobile devices. Any help on that regard will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Link of the library: https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

Answer (score 27):

Maybe you want to do it with CSS but it can be easy with JS. You can use optional settings object on your JS file where you initialize AOS like this:

```
AOS.init({disable: 'mobile'});
```

Here  you can use following values: 'phone', 'tablet', 'mobile', boolean, expression or function

For more options check https://github.com/michalsnik/aos

Comment: Is there any way I can disable it for a certain element?

Comment: This may have worked in the past but today it does not

Answer (score 8):

You can use this js to specify when exactly you want to disable it.

```
AOS.init({
  disable: function() {
    var maxWidth = 800;
    return window.innerWidth < maxWidth;
  }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work as of current

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions worked for me,

The only way I was able to disable animations on mobile was by wrapping the content of aos.css within a media query such as:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:750px) {
 
 /* paste here ​all the content of the aos.css file */    

}
```

This works perfectly because it doesn't overide CSS that elements could have, disables the animation without interring. Combined with Mahidul Isalm Mukto's response It was the full solution.

Comment: Same here, none of the top solutions here work, only way is to hack the css

Answer (score 2):

Similar to An's answer, but the class is different. This will work as of 2022 - change class to 'aos-animate':

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .aos-animate {

    -o-transition-property: none !important;
    -moz-transition-property: none !important;
    -ms-transition-property: none !important;
    -webkit-transition-property: none !important;
    transition-property: none !important;

    -o-transform: none !important;
    -moz-transform: none !important;
    -ms-transform: none !important;
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
    transform: none !important;

    -webkit-animation: none !important;
    -moz-animation: none !important;
    -o-animation: none !important;
    -ms-animation: none !important;
    animation: none !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this on div you input AOS animation

```
@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
    .class-name {
      opacity: 1 !important;
      transform: translate(0) scale(1) !important;
    }
}
```

it's worked for me rn

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi! Please explain briefly what your code does and how it solves the problem. Thank you :)

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, perfect answer and explanation

Answer (score 1):

Add media query to the css link, so you won't load the css on mobile at all.

Change css link from this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" />
```

to this (change the min width variable as you wish, 550px (is viewport not actual screen resolution) covers 99.9% of all mobile phones):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" media="(min-width: 550px)" />
```

And you can do the same for AOS javascript to load only on non mobile devices. If non mobile, script is loaded at the end of html body element.

```
<script>
    let matchMedia = window.matchMedia("(min-width:550px)");
    if(!matchMedia.matches){
       let myNonMobileScript = document.createElement("script");
       myNonMobileScript.src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js" 
       document.body.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", myNonMobileScript);
       AOS.init();
    }
</script>
```

If you want to catch screen size changes, css will do it automatically but for javascript you need to add event listener.

```
    <script>
    function loadScriptOnlyNonMobileDevices() {
            let matchMedia = window.matchMedia("(min-width:550px)");
            if(!matchMedia.matches){
               let myNonMobileScript = document.createElement("script");
               myNonMobileScript.src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js" 
               document.body.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", myNonMobileScript);
               AOS.init();
            }
    }
// on page load checks the screen size
    loadScriptOnlyNonMobileDevices(); 
// when screen size changes checks the screen size again to load js file if needed.
    window.onresize = loadScriptOnlyNonMobileDevices; 
        </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one it worked for me:

```
/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    .animated {
        /*CSS transitions*/
        -o-transition-property: none !important;
        -moz-transition-property: none !important;
        -ms-transition-property: none !important;
        -webkit-transition-property: none !important;
        transition-property: none !important;
        /*CSS transforms*/
        -o-transform: none !important;
        -moz-transform: none !important;
        -ms-transform: none !important;
        -webkit-transform: none !important;
        transform: none !important;
        /*CSS animations*/
        -webkit-animation: none !important;
        -moz-animation: none !important;
        -o-animation: none !important;
        -ms-animation: none !important;
        animation: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the code to my style.css file. But it's still the same. Showing animation to mobile devices. Did I miss something while adding the code? Thanks @Ngyen

Comment: Prefix "aos-" is missing. You must add it in front of the ".animated" class, leaving "aos-animated"

Comment: This no longer works